# Перевод кода python в код C

Tags: python, python-3.x, c

Есть вот такая простая задача[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо реализовать ее решение на языке C, с которым я никогда в жизни не работала. Перерыв кучу информации в интернете, я вроде написала подходящий код и решила проверить правильность реализации. Переписала задачу на python и получила абсолютно другие ответы.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Код Python:

```
import math

b = int(input('enter number: '))
k,s,x = 0,0,-5
while x<=15:
    if x<-2: z = b * 2.71**x
    elif x<=2 and x>=-2: z = b * (x**2+ 1)
    else: z = math.log1p(math.fabs(x + b))
    y = z**3+2.71**(b*z)
    if y < 0.5 and y!=0: k+=1
    elif y > 5 and y!=0: s += y
    print(x, ' ', y, ' ', z)
    x+=0.4
print(k, s)
```

Результат:

```
при х=-5
z=1.1859572142878254
y=0.03420767441375836
при х=2.2
z=35912.03673677687
y=2.1041341542702074
при х=5
z=155279.32808796052
y=2.3978952727983707
```

Код C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double x, dx = 0.4, s = 0, z, y;
int k = 0, b=5;
const e = 2.71;

int main() {
    printf("input b\n");
    x = -5;
    while(x<=15) {

        if (x<-2) z = b*pow(e, x);
        else if (x <= 2 && x >= -2) z = b*(pow(x,2) + 1);
        else z = log(fabs(x+b));

        y = pow(z,3) + pow(e, (b*z));

        if (y < 0.5 && y != 0) k += 1;
        else if (y > 5 && y != 0) s += y;

        printf("x=%.1f; z=%.3f; y=%.3f \n", x, z, y);
        x += dx;}

    printf("b=%d s=%6.10f k=%d\n", b, s, k);
    return 0;}
```

Результат:

```
при х=-5
z=0.156
y=1.722
при х=2.2
z=1.974
y=943.719
при х=5
z=2.303
y=2934.583
```

Comment: Для начала нет считывания `b`.

Comment: Для начала включите предупреждения компилятора. Затем выполните программы построчно и найдите момент, когда результаты начинают расходиться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ошибки в Си:

- > ```
  > const e = 2.71;
  > ```

  Здесь опущен тип, поэтому по древним традициям Си компилятор считает,
  что он `int`, что само собой не то что имелось ввиду. Вообще говоря,
  компилятор должен был бы предупредить, что здесь что-то не так. А 
  удовлетворять всё о чём попросит компилятор — хорошая идея, которая
  помогает избежать большинства ошибок.
  Правильно будет:

  ```
  const double e = 2.71;
  ```
- > ```
  > long double x, dx = 0.4, s = 0, z, y;
  > // ...
  >   else if (x <= 2 && x >= -2) z = b*(pow(x,2) + 1);
  >   else z = log(fabs(x+b));
  > printf("x=%.1f; z=%.3f; y=%.3f \n", x, z, y);
  > ```

  Переменные объявлены как `long double`, а спецификатор формата `%f` и
  функции `fabs` и `pow` применим только к типу `double`.
  Соответственно нужно одно из двух:

  - Объявить переменные как `double`:

    ```
    double x, dx = 0.4, s = 0, z, y;
    ```
  - Использовать функции `fabsl()`, `powl()` и спецификатор `%lf`:

    ```
    printf("x=%.1f; z=%.3f; y=%.3f \n", x, z, y);
    ```

#### Менее критичные ошибки и рекомендации

- Использование глобальных переменных (объявленных вне какой-либо функции) без особой на то необходимости — моветон, лучше объявлять их все внутри функции `main ()`.
- > ```
  > pow(e, x);
  > ```

  Для экспоненты, как и во всех языках есть отдельная фунция `exp()`. Таким образом, самостоятельно объявлять `e` не надо. Тем более такое значение будет достаточно сильно неточное (`y` будет отличаться уже во втором знаке).

  В python она тоже есть — `math.exp()`.
- > ```
  > y != 0
  > ```

  Сравнение чисел с плавающей точкой, особенно полученных вычислением, на точное равенство — плохая идея.
- > ```
  > return 0;}
  > ```

  Завершающие скобки обычно записывают на отдельной строке.
- Из тривиального: собственно отсутствует ввод `b`.

### Ошибки в Python

> ```
> print(x, ' ', y, ' ', z)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> при х=-5
> z=1.1859572142878254
> y=0.03420767441375836
> ```

Перепутаны местами `y` и `z`.

> ```
> else: z = math.log1p(math.fabs(x + b))
> ```

`math.log1p(x)` вычисляет `ln(1+x)`, что явно не то что указано в задаче. Здесь должно быть `math.log()`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!